# Replace "NULL" values to "0" via SQL Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Good day! I am stuck with my query. I want to replace my NULL values into zeroes.

My Syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT (B.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + B.MIDDLE_INITIAL + ' ' + B.SURNAME) As 'Name', DATENAME(MONTH, A.COVERAGE_DATE) As 'Month', SUM(ISNULL((A.AMOUNT),0)) As 'Amount' 
FROM Transactions A, PledgerProfile B 
WHERE A.PLEDGER_ID = B.PLEDGER_ID AND DATENAME(Year, A.COVERAGE_DATE) = '2021' 
GROUP BY (B.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + B.MIDDLE_INITIAL + ' ' + B.SURNAME), DATENAME(MONTH, A.COVERAGE_DATE)) AS MonthlySalesData 
PIVOT(SUM(AMOUNT) 
FOR Month IN ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May], [June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November], [December])) AS MNamePivot
```

Calling a friend. Can someone look into it and check my syntax? I appreciate any feedback. Thank you!

My Output:

[image: My Output]

Comment: On a side note, you should really avoid the old style joins and use an explicit join

Comment: I'd suggest you to use the clause case-when-else for each column. Like this: case when [January] is NULL then 0.0 else [January] end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than top `SELECT *` you can specify the columns/values via `IsNull()`

**Example**

```
SELECT Name
      ,[January]   = isnull([January],0)
      ,[February]  = isnull([February],0)
      ,[March]     = isnull([March],0)
      ,[April]     = isnull([April],0)
      ,[May]       = isnull([May],0)
      ,[June]      = isnull([June],0)
      ,[July]      = isnull([July],0)
      ,[August]    = isnull([August],0)
      ,[September] = isnull([September],0)
      ,[October]   = isnull([October],0)
      ,[November]  = isnull([November],0)
      ,[December]  = isnull([December],0)
      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select (pp.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + pp.MIDDLE_INITIAL + ' ' + pp.SURNAME) As 'Name',
       sum(case when month(t.coverage_date) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as jan,
       sum(case when month(t.coverage_date) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as feb,
       . . .
from Transactions t join
     PledgerProfile pp 
     on pp.PLEDGER_ID = t.PLEDGER_ID 
where t.coverage_date >= '2021-01-01' and t.coverage_date < '2022-01-01'
group by (pp.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + pp.MIDDLE_INITIAL + ' ' + pp.SURNAME);
```

No subquery is needed.

Notes:

- *Never* use commass in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- Use meaningful table aliases, not arbitrary letters such as `a` and `b`.
- For date comparisons, use direct date comparisons.  This allows the use of an index, if appropriate.